# A do-while loop keeps saying the same thing

Tags: c

How come this loop always says "Pick 's' or 'h' try again" when I pick 's' or 'h'? I feel like the logic is correct I just don't know it says that no matter what I put even if it is 's' or h'.

```
do {
    printf("Do you want to (H)it or (S)tand?");
    scanf("%ch", &decision);
    tolower(decision);
    if (decision != 'h' && decision != 's') {
        printf("Pick 's' or 'h'. Try again.\n");
        printf("Do you want to (H)it or (S)tand?");
        scanf("%ch", &decision);
        tolower(decision);
    }
    if (decision == 'h') {
        playershand = add_card_to_hand(&playershand, card);
        printf("Your cards:\n");
        print_hand(playershand);
        playerscore = blackjack_value(playershand);
        printf("Score = %d\n", playerscore);
    }
    if (decision == 's') {
        add_card_to_hand(&dealershand, card);
        print_hand(dealershand);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code using a debugger?

Comment: Have you rad the manual page for `scanf` and what does it tell you about `scanf("%ch", &decision);`?

Comment: Ditto with the line `tolower(decision);`

Comment: Its "%c" I know, and what does that mean @EdHeal

Comment: Have you tried to read the manual page and digest 9t - https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf